# Passing value from selected row to view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I tried pass value from selected row to view controller. Log return null value in new view controller.Where is my mistake ?

```
 2013-06-18 17:28:59.394 App[1790:c07] ID is Here: 35023

 2013-06-18 17:28:59.397 App[1790:c07] Value in Next view  (null)

2013-06-18 17:28:59.398 App[1790:c07] Label is Here <UILabel: 0x9139810; 
frame = (14 140; 255 16); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; 
autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x915ab10>>
```

TableViewController Code :

```
NSString *localStringValue;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *value = [myArray objectAtIndex:row];

    DetailViewController *second=[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil] ;

    second.PassID=value;

    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];

    localStringValue = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"ID is Here: %@", value);
}
```

Next View Controller Codes:

.h

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *PassID;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *PassID;
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

.m codes

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

   label.text=PassID;
    NSLog(@"Label is Here %@",label);

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Try to print self.label.

Comment: Having the iVar `label` and the property `label` cause mass confusion everywhere.  Remove one or the other (from your needs I would say remove the iVar).  Xcode automatically creates an iVar for properties, usually _(iVar).

Comment: try by changing the statement sequence present first and then assign value
[self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
second.label=value;

Comment: u can declear varibale and access it's very easy in appdelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *value = [myArray objectAtIndex:row];

    DetailViewController *second=[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil] ;

/// second.PassID=value; ///Remove the line here


    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];

    second.PassID=value; ///assign the value after presenting


    localStringValue = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"ID is Here: %@", value);
}
```

Comment: in next view controller .m - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    
   
 label.text=PassID;
    NSLog(@"Label is Here %@",PassID);
    
    [super viewDidLoad];}
Log : Label is Here (null)

Answer (score 0):

Try `NSLog(@"Label is Here %@", self.label);` and see if that works.

The `NSString *label;` ivar in your .h file isn't necessary, as you're also declaring a property with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in DetailViewController.h

> ```
> @interface DetailViewController : UIViewController 
> @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *label;
> ```

in DetailViewController.m

```
-(void)setLabelText:(NSString *)label{
    if(_label!=label)
        _label = label;
}
```

and use function

> [second setLabelText:value];

and print with

> NSLog(@"Label is Here %@",self.label);

Comment: It is same.Return null in new view controller.